# After configure pound get error "An internal server error occurred. Please try again later"

Tags: apache, drupal, drupal-7, pound

I have configure pound on my Linux system. my site is working fine but some time i get "An internal server error occurred. Please try again later". I have changed the alive in pound.conf file 15 to 100 but it didn't work. i have also changed the timeout and keepalivetimeout in Apache.conf file it didn't work.

have anyone solution for this problem?

Comment: Hi Ankit, have you found any solution as I am also facing the same issue.